# How to implement setInterval in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, setinterval

In javascript i can use function setInterval("functionName',time); to functionName after time delay. 
How i can use a function like setInterval in Delphi?

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Create a `TTimer`, and set its interval to `time`. Then create an `onTimer` event and call the `functionName` in the event procedure.

Answer (score 2):

There is the `TTimer` component for doing that

you can take a look at this [tutorial](http://sheepdogguides.com/dt2f.htm)